# RODBC not following order to dataframe when importing into access mdb file

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

As title, I created a dataframe and import it into `mdb` file using `RODBC` in `R`. Things are going OK, but I realize that the table shown in `mdb` file is not having the same order as my dataframe. I tried using `row.names(temp.df) <- NULL` after ordering, but the order is still kinda random.

It is not a very big issue as long as the two datasets are the same, but I wonder why this will happen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Databases generally have no concept of ordering of their rows, by design. If you want a particular sorting order, then you have to put "ORDER BY" in your SQL when working with a database and sort on a column.